# What is the correct order in the phrase " If I just could get...." or " If I could just get..."?

Tags: phrases

I want to know the correct order of the words **just** and **could** in phrases like

> If I just could get without any trouble I would appreciate it

or

> If I could just get ...

Which part of grammar deals with these stuffs?

Answer (score 4):

The correct order is:

> If I **could** just get....

The same would be true of other helping (auxilliary, modal) verb constructions.

> If I **had** only seen...
>
> If I **did** scarcely seem....

But the position of the adverb in a sentence is governed by a number of factors.

You will find useful guidance and examples at:

https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/grammar/word-order/adverb-position

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/positions-of-adverbs