# soon will disappear / will soon disappear / will disappear soon. Are all three correct in this context?

Tags: grammar

This is a text originally in Portuguese that I am trying to translate into English. Are all three forms acceptable?

I love the sight of these old colonial style houses on the way to my school. But they **soon will disappear** / But they **will soon disappear** / But they **will disappear soon**. The land on which they are located was sold to a big construction company and a large shopping center will be built in its place.

Comment: It's generally not considered idiomatic to position an adverb between the subject and a modal or auxiliary verb. This is because modal and auxiliary verbs typically play a supportive role in the sentence, and placing an adverb between the subject and the verb disrupts the natural flow of the sentence. So you shouldn't say things like *They soon will arrive* or *You soon can go*. We *usually* put the adverb after the "complete" verb phrase *(They will arrive soon, You can go soon)*, but sometimes "fronting" it to before the main verb *(They will soon arrive, You can soon go)* adds emphasis.

Comment: Here is an answer to a related question you might find helpful: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/166933/171527

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add to the comments from @FumbleFingers and @Quack E Duck.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=they+soon+will+_VERB_%2C%28they+will+soon+_VERB_+*+0.1%29%2Cthey+will+_VERB_+soon&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shows that **they will "verb" soon** is almost twice as common as **they soon will "verb"**.

The most common is the version that gives added emphasis, **they will soon "verb"**.  Note that I have applied a factor in this Ngram.